# Get names from different table in child-grandparent relationship

Tags: mysql, parent-child

I have three tables:

```
CREATE TABLE category (id integer, parent_id integer);
CREATE TABLE category_name (id integer, name (varchar(20), language_id);
CREATE TABLE language (language_id integer, language_name);
```

I am able to get the child-parent-grandparent relationship with the following statement:

```
SELECT c.id, c.parent_id, p.parent_id 
FROM category AS p, category AS c 
WHERE p.id = c.parent_id AND p.parent_id IS NOT NULL;
```

But I need to get the names as well for both child, parent and grandparent from the table category_name where the language_id = 3

The query to get the name, without the child-parent-grandparent relation would be something like this:

```
SELECT c.id, n.name
FROM category c
LEFT JOIN category_name n ON c.id = n.id AND language_ID = 3
```

But how can the two statements be joined into one, so that I actually get three name columns out? 
That is, each row should have the IDs and names for itself, its parent and its grandparent (if the latter exist)

How can I proceed to make this combined query?

Here are the tables and some sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE category (id integer, parent_id integer);
INSERT INTO category VALUES (1,null);
INSERT INTO category VALUES (2,null);
INSERT INTO category VALUES (3,1);
INSERT INTO category VALUES (4,2);
INSERT INTO category VALUES (5,2);
INSERT INTO category VALUES (6,4);
INSERT INTO category VALUES (7,2);
INSERT INTO category VALUES (8,7);
INSERT INTO category VALUES (9,7);
INSERT INTO category VALUES (10,7);
INSERT INTO category VALUES (11,3);

CREATE TABLE category_name (id integer, name varchar(20), language_id integer);
INSERT INTO category_name VALUES (1, 'CDs', 3);
INSERT INTO category_name VALUES (2, 'Books', 3);
INSERT INTO category_name VALUES (3, 'Music', 3);
INSERT INTO category_name VALUES (4, 'Novels', 3);
INSERT INTO category_name VALUES (5, 'Childrens books', 3);
INSERT INTO category_name VALUES (6, 'European', 3);
INSERT INTO category_name VALUES (7, 'Science', 3);
INSERT INTO category_name VALUES (8, 'Math', 3);
INSERT INTO category_name VALUES (9, 'Informatics', 3);
INSERT INTO category_name VALUES (10, 'Physics', 3);
INSERT INTO category_name VALUES (11, 'Classic', 3);
INSERT INTO category_name VALUES (1, 'CDs', 4);
INSERT INTO category_name VALUES (2, 'Livres', 4);
INSERT INTO category_name VALUES (3, 'Musique', 4);
INSERT INTO category_name VALUES (4, 'Romans', 4);

CREATE TABLE language (language_id integer, language_name varchar(15));
INSERT INTO language (3, 'English');
INSERT INTO language (4, 'French');
```

Here is how I would like to get out some sample (for c.id = 5 and 8):

```
c.id | c.parent_id | p.parent_id | nameChild          | nameParent | nameGrandparent
5    | 2           | null        | 'Children's books' | 'Books'    | null
8    | 7           | 2           | 'Math'             | 'Science'  | 'Books'
```

---

I have tried the following code, but it gives 
Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'p.parent_id' in 'on clause'

```
SELECT c.id, c.parent_id, p.parent_id, nc.name, np.name, ng.name 
FROM category1 AS p, category1 AS c 
LEFT JOIN category_name1 AS nc ON c.id = nc.id AND nc.language_id = 3
LEFT JOIN category_name1 AS np ON c.parent_id = np.id AND np.language_id = 3
LEFT JOIN category_name1 AS ng ON p.parent_id = ng.id AND ng.language_id = 3 AND p.parent_id IS NOT NULL
WHERE p.id = c.parent_id AND p.parent_id IS NOT NULL;
```

I don't have a problem getting out the child and parent names, but the grandparent name seems to be out of my grasp :(

And below is the code working!

```
SELECT x.id, x.pid, x.gpid, 
nc.name childName, np.name parentName, ng.name gpName 
FROM 
(SELECT  c.id , c.parent_id AS pid, p.parent_id AS gpid
FROM
category AS c
LEFT JOIN category AS p ON p.id = c.parent_id
) x


LEFT JOIN category_name AS nc ON x.id = nc.id AND nc.language_id = 3
LEFT JOIN category_name AS np ON x.pid = np.id AND np.language_id = 3
LEFT JOIN category_name AS ng ON x.gpid = ng.id AND ng.language_id = 3;
```

Comment: Can you please show us some sample data and expected results based on the sample data? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT 
c.id AS childId, cname.name AS childName,
p.id AS parentId, pname.name AS parentName,
g.id AS grandparentId, gname.name AS grandparentName
FROM category p
INNER JOIN category c ON (p.id = c.parent_id)
LEFT JOIN category g ON (p.parent_id = g.id)
LEFT JOIN category_name cname ON (c.id = cname.id AND cname.language_ID = 3)
LEFT JOIN category_name pname ON (p.id = pname.id AND pname.language_ID = 3)
LEFT JOIN category_name gname ON (g.id = gname.id AND gname.language_ID = 3)
WHERE p.parent_id IS NOT NULL;
```

I feel like there should be a neater way to do this but can't see it at the moment.

Comment: didn't see this one for some reason.

Comment: This one also works really well. And a VIEW can be created based on it, something that does not work with the first one with a subquery, apparently. But I don't get the first categories, that is, the grandparents are not listed as children.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this out and comment. Both queries and results are based on my own sample.

- [SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/47f88/2)

This query selects `language name`, `category name` with `language id =` something, group by `parent id`.

Query:

```
select l.language_name, cl.name, c.parent_id
from category c
left join 
category_name cl
on c.parent_id = cl.id
inner join 
language l
on cl.language_id = l.language_id
where l.language_id = 30
group by c.parent_id
;
```

Results:

```
LANGUAGE_NAME   NAME    PARENT_ID
eng             cat4c   4
```

The following query is selecting `category name` and `parent id` for each `language`.

Query:

```
select l.language_name, cl.name, c.parent_id
from language l
left join 
category_name cl
on cl.language_id = l.language_id
left join 
category c
on c.parent_id = cl.id
group by l.language_id
;
```

Results:

```
LANGUAGE_NAME   NAME    PARENT_ID
jpn             cat1    (null)
kor             cat3    3
eng             cat4    4
```

### EDIT AS PER OP'S UPDATED QUESTION WITH SAMPLE DATA & EXPECTED RESULTS

- [SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/593543/1)

Query:

```
select x.id, x.pid, x.gpid, 
cl.name ccat, cl2.name pcat, cl3.name gpcat
from
(SELECT c.id , c.parent_id as pid, 
p.parent_id gpid
FROM category AS c
left join category AS p 
on p.id = c.parent_id 
WHERE c.id in (5, 8)
) x
left join 
category_name cl
on cl.id = x.id
left join category_name cl2
on cl2.id = x.pid
left join category_name cl3
on cl3.id = x.gpid
group by x.id
;
```

Results:

```
ID  PID     GPID    CCAT        PCAT    GPCAT
5   2       (null)  Children    Books   (null)
8   7       2       Math        Science Books
```

Comment: but how can I combine it with the child-parent-grandparent query at the same time?

Comment: Sorry can you please update your question with some sample data to your tables and show us the expected results based on that?

Comment: @user1956527 I have updated my answer as per your question updates, please try it and comment. And if you require `language name` as well, then look into the updated sqlfiddle demo :)

Comment: @user1956527 well the other answer doesn't seem to restrict the data. Anyway whichever works for u... Plus you didn't mentioned about creating a `view` based on this query in the first place in your question either!